# Issues with Unicode symbols in some applications running in Terminal.app and iTerm2

Tags: keyboard, terminal, bash, unicode, zsh

```
Darwin DeoGloria 13.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.3.0: Tue Jun  3 21:27:35 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.110.17~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Fresh user account. Terminal.app and iTerm2 with UTF-8 set. Accented characters work fine in all applications ("å,ä,ö,é"). But some (wide?) unicode chars is not showing in some command line applications. I first discovered it in weechat, but in the bash shell it works fine.

In stock Mavericks bash:

```
DeoGloria:~ test$ echo -e "\xE2\x9A\x91"
⚑
```

Copying and pasting the flag char with mouse.

```
DeoGloria:~ test$ ⚑
-bash: ⚑: command not found
```

bash is working as expected. Starting default zsh, no config done

```
DeoGloria:~ test$ zsh
DeoGloria:~ test$ echo -e "\xE2\x9A\x91"
⚑
```

Showing alright. But not when I paste:

```
DeoGloria% <2691>
zsh: command not found: \u2691
```

Locale settings:

```
DeoGloria% locale
LANG="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Starting emacs or vi from zsh and pasting "⚑" works fine. It doesn't work in nano. I get an non-visual character.

I suspected some issues with ncurses, but bash, zsh, nano, emacs are all linked with

```
/usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.0)
```

I'm out of ideas. Any pointers?

Comment: Similar question here, but no complete answer: https://superuser.com/questions/583031/how-can-i-get-zsh-to-display-international-characters-properly

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! I did some tests on my side.

#### zsh

```
xXx:~/ $ <2691>                                                                                                                                                                                              
zsh: command not found: \u2691
xXx:~/ $                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
zsh: command not found: 
xXx:~/ $ ℃                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
zsh: command not found: ℃
```

I did also several tests with other shells and results are not the same:

#### sh

```
sh-3.2$ ⚑
sh: ⚑: command not found
```

#### bash

Ok, that should be the same as `sh`:

```
bash-3.2$ ⚑
bash: ⚑: command not found
```

#### csh/tcsh

```
[LeBouc-xXx:~] xXx% \U+2691
⚑: Command not found.
```

---

Apparently, all that shells are not set with the same input/output options. I tried with xterm/terminal and iTerm2 to see if I could be a software dependant problem. That's the same everywhere.

I don't have the time to search/read that but you might find some useful informations about the zsh line editor [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/zsh_toc.html#SEC_Contents).

If you find it, keep me up-to-date, I would be pleased to have the final answer to your question.